# How to catch Tibrv RVD.DISCONNECTED message in Java?

Tags: java, tibco

I have a long running Tibrv connection from a Java process.

I was surprised to see this log entry today (printed on stderr):

> 2018-02-01 08:15:44 RV: TIB/Rendezvous Error Not Handled by Process:
>   {ADV_CLASS="WARN" ADV_SOURCE="SYSTEM" ADV_NAME="RVD.DISCONNECTED"}

**What is the right way to catch this error and reconnect?**

My process needs to be fault tolerant.  (I think the server on the other side was rebooted.)

Sample connection code:

```
Tibrv.open(Tibrv.IMPL_NATIVE);
final TibrvRvdTransport tibrvRvdTransport =
    new TibrvRvdTransport(tibrvService, nullableTibrvNetwork, tibrvDaemon);
```

According to the [official Tibrv docs](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/rendezvous/8.3.1_january_2011/pdf/tib_rv_concepts.pdf) (p282), there is a *System Advisory Message* called `_RV.WARN.SYSTEM.RVD.DISCONNECTED`.  However, I don't know the correct way to listen for this message, nor attempt recovery upon receipt.

Answer (score 1):

This took me a while to figure out, so I am answering my own question.

In short, the Tibrv Java library uses a private thread to automatically monitor for disconnect and re-connect.  The purpose of 'user-space' monitoring is to provide gracefully handling of these events (fault tolerance, etc.).

The technical solution is to listen for two special RVD messages:

- `_RV.WARN.SYSTEM.RVD.DISCONNECTED`
- `_RV.INFO.SYSTEM.RVD.CONNECTED`

A single `TibrvListener` with subject wildcard can be used.

```
final String subjectWildcard = "_RV.*.SYSTEM.RVD.*";
final Object nullableClosure = null;
new TibrvListener(
    Tibrv.defaultQueue(),
    // @NotThreadSafe
    new TibrvMsgCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMsg(TibrvListener tibrvListener, TibrvMsg tibrvMsg) {
            final String sendSubject = tibrvMsg.getSendSubject();
            if ("_RV.WARN.SYSTEM.RVD.DISCONNECTED".equals(sendSubject)) {
                // TODO
            }
            else if ("_RV.INFO.SYSTEM.RVD.CONNECTED".equals(sendSubject)) {
                // TODO
            }
        }
    },
    tibrvRvdTransport, subjectWildcard, nullableClosure);

// Next: Setup a daemon thread to dispatch incoming Tibrv messages.
{
    final Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        final TibrvQueue tibrvQueue = Tibrv.defaultQueue();
        while (true) {
            try {
                tibrvQueue.dispatch();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

[Credit for `TibrvListener` and `TibrvQueue.dispatch()`](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/198974/Tibco-Rendezvous-Listener-Sample)

How to test disconnect and re-connect events:

1. Create a Tibrv listener from command line:

   - `$ tibrvlisten -service 8800 -daemon tcp:8800 TEST.MESSAGE`
2. Send a test message from command line:

   - `$ tibrvsend -service 8800 -daemon ${tibrvlisten.hostname}:8800 TEST.MESSAGE hello`
   - `tibrvlisten` should log: `subject=TEST.MESSAGE, message={DATA="hello"}`
3. In Java, connect to the Tibrv listener: `new TibrvRvdTransport("8800", null, "${tibrvlisten.hostname}:8800")`
4. Stop `tibrvlisten` with Ctrl+C, then kill background process `rvd`, e.g., `$ ps -efjww | egrep 'rvd +-listen' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill`
5. In Java, upon receiving disconnect event, immediately send message:

   - `final TibrvMsg m = new TibrvMsg();
     m.setSendSubject("TEST.MESSAGE"); 
     m.add("DATA", "hello"); 
     tibrvRvdTransport.send(m);`
   - `send()` will fail with `TibrvException`:
     error=21, message="Could not connect to daemon"
   - Public field `int TibrvException.error` values can be found here:
     `TibrvStatus`, e.g., `DAEMON_NOT_CONNECTED = 21`
6. Restart `tibrvlisten` and wait for Java background thread to automatically re-connect.
7. In Java, upon receiving re-connect event, messages may again be sent without error.

[Credit for `tibrvlisten`](https://it.toolbox.com/question/usage-of-tibrvsend-and-tibrvlisten-052405)